# why is the "sizeToFit" call required in this code?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, sizetofit

Anyone able to highlight why the "[aLabel sizeToFit]" line is required in this code below, taken from [here](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/).

That is, the CGRect created has already been sized based on the text font size, so why would the sizeToFit be required?  Or is it because whilst they calculated the correct CGRect size they actually didn't set the pre-agreed font (system font) to the UILabel yet?  (and therefore effectively called sizeToFit instead of setting the font)

```
- (CGRect)RAD_frameForCellLabelWithSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size {
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 50;
    CGFloat height = [self RAD_textHeightForSystemFontOfSize:size] + 10.0;
    return CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, width, height);
}

- (void)RAD_resizeLabel:(UILabel *)aLabel WithSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size {
    aLabel.frame = [self RAD_frameForCellLabelWithSystemFontOfSize:size];
    aLabel.text = self;
    [aLabel sizeToFit];    // WHY IS THIS REQUIRED
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs:

> Call this method when you want to
>   resize the current view so that it
>   uses the most appropriate amount of
>   space. Specific UIKit views resize
>   themselves according to their own
>   internal needs. In some cases, if a
>   view does not have a superview, it may
>   size itself to the screen bounds.
>   Thus, if you want a given view to size
>   itself to its parent view, you should
>   add it to the parent view before
>   calling this method.

Choose the right one, that is appropriate for your case.

Comment: but isn't it true that the allocation of the CGRect (which has been specifically sized) is in effect setting the size of the UILabel (and I understand UILabel is actually the/a view)?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes UILabel is subclass of UIView. Forgot to add this from docs: Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews.   So if that label has subviews, then this is the answer. However you can determine that for sure: comment out that line and see what happens:)

Comment: ok - for the moment then I think what you're saying is it may not really be necessary in this code (i.e. might not do anything)?

Comment: really I don't know (cause it's application specific). I've just listed all possible reasons.